# How to create a makefile that will place object code in different folder

Tags: makefile

I am very new to Makefile. I had build the following makefile(Which don't work).I wan't put genarated object codes in differnt folder(the folder is in current directory).

```
$ ls
main.cpp  Makefile  object_code  Time.cpp  Time_.h
```

how can I do this ??

```
VER = Debug
CC = g++


OBJECTFIELS = ./object_code/main.o ./object_code/Time.o

../$(VER)/main: $(OBJECTFIELS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTFIELS) -o $@

$(OBJECTFIELS): Time_.h

./object_code/main.o: main.cpp

./object_code/Time.o: Time.cpp

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTFIELS) main
```

this is error.

```
$ make
g++ ./object_code/main.o ./object_code/Time.o -o ../Debug/main
g++: error: ./object_code/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./object_code/Time.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8: recipe for target '../Debug/main' failed
make: *** [../Debug/main] Error 1
```

please this is last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you can possibly get that output given the makefile you've posted here.

Either the object files already exist in which case the link will succeed rather than printing that error.

Or the object files don't exist in which case make will complain because it doesn't know how to make them.  There must be some difference between the makefile you're using and the one you've posted here.

In any event, make knows how to build a file `foo.o` from a file `foo.cpp` for any string `foo`.  There's a built-in rule that tells it how to do that.

But, make doesn't know how to build a file `./object_code/foo.o` from a file `foo.cpp`, regardless of `foo`.  There's no built-in rule that tells make how to build object files in some random *other* directory.  If you want make to do that, you'll have to tell it how.  You should remove the lines:

```
./object_code/main.o: main.cpp

./object_code/Time.o: Time.cpp
```

and replace them with a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) describing how to build object files into the `object_code` directory (I'm using `CXX` as the compiler variable here: by convention `CC` is the C compiler and `CXX` is the C++ compiler, and you should always stick with convention unless there's a good reason not to):

```
VER = Debug
CXX = g++

OBJECTFIELS = ./object_code/main.o ./object_code/Time.o

../$(VER)/main: $(OBJECTFIELS)
        $(CXX) $(OBJECTFIELS) -o $@

$(OBJECTFIELS): Time_.h

./object_code/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm $(OBJECTFIELS) main
```